# How to get laravel pivot table records in views?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have three tables.

> Users: id,name
>
> Courses: id,user_id,name
>
> Order: id,user_id,course_id (
> Pivot table)

How can i make sure in course view that this user has purchased this particular course using Laravel eloquent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to define a many to many relationship between your models:

```
class User extends Model {
  public function courses() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class);
  }
}
```

Once you have it, you can easily check if User has bought access to a Course with given ID with:

```
if ($user->courses()->find($courseId)) {
  // user has access to course with given $courseId
}
```

If you simply want to an error to be raised when course was not bought, replace a call to **find()** with a call to **findOrFail()**:

```
if ($user->courses()->findOrFail($courseId)) {
  // user has access to course with given $courseId
}
```